# adding xticks to subplots in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I do this

```
def example_plot(ax, somedata, somedata2, title, xlab, ylab, fontsize=12):

    ax.plot(somedata, color='b')
    ax.plot(somedata2, color='g')
    ax.locator_params(nbins=3)
    ax.set_xlabel(xlab, fontsize=8)
    ax.set_ylabel(ylab, fontsize=10)
    ax.set_title(title, fontsize=10)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 
fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
ax1.grid(color='r', linestyle='-', linewidth=1)
ax2.grid(color='r', linestyle='-', linewidth=1)
ax3.grid(color='r', linestyle='-', linewidth=1)
ax4.grid(color='r', linestyle='-', linewidth=1)

example_plot(ax1,cumulative1,survival1, t1, xlbl1, ylbl1) 
example_plot(ax2,cumulative2,survival2, t2, xlbl2, ylbl2)
example_plot(ax3,cumulative3,survival3, t3, xlbl3, ylbl3)
example_plot(ax4,cumulative4,survival4, t4, xlbl4, ylbl4)

plt.tight_layout(pad= 0.4, w_pad= 0.5, h_pad = 1.0)
```

My question revolves around applying custom xticks to every subplot.
No matter how many times or where I place the lines

```
plt.xticks(np.arange(0,100, step = 10))
plt.xlim(0, 100)
```

They only wind up applying to the 4th subplot.
How to define custom xticks for each subplot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to apply the operations on the axes, `plt` manipulates the last axis used. You should read [the documentation, what kind of manipulations you can perform on the Axes class.](https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes) For your example, you would need `set_xticks` and `set_xlim`:

```
def example_plot(ax, somedata, somedata2, title, xlab, ylab, fontsize=12):

    ax.plot(somedata, color='b')
    ax.plot(somedata2, color='g')
    ax.locator_params(nbins=3)
    ax.set_xlabel(xlab, fontsize=8)
    ax.set_ylabel(ylab, fontsize=10)
    ax.set_title(title, fontsize=10)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 
fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
ax1.grid(color='r', linestyle='-', linewidth=1)
ax2.grid(color='r', linestyle='-', linewidth=1)
ax3.grid(color='r', linestyle='-', linewidth=1)
ax4.grid(color='r', linestyle='-', linewidth=1)

example_plot(ax1,np.random.rand(10),np.random.rand(20), "A", "x A", "y A") 
example_plot(ax2,np.random.rand(30),np.random.rand(40), "B", "x B", "y B")
example_plot(ax3,np.random.rand(10),np.random.rand(40), "C", "x C", "y C")
example_plot(ax4,np.random.rand(20),np.random.rand(50), "D", "x D", "y D")

plt.tight_layout(pad= 0.4, w_pad= 0.5, h_pad = 1.0) 

ax1.set_xticks(range(0, 20, 5))
ax2.set_xlim(10, 40)
ax3.set_xlim(0, 50)
ax4.set_xticks(range(20, 50, 5))

plt.show()
```

Sample output:

[image]